# JS Beautify: preserve comment indentation

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, js-beautify

I'm currently using the [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify#options) plugin for SublimeText2 and editing the `.jsbeautifyrc`. I was unable to find an attribute in the config docs that I *think* is manipulable: **preserve comment indentation**.

My desired output matches my initial format:

```
// This comment isn't indented so I can fold all of the code it refers to
   function fooBar() {
      ... do stuff
   };
```

Comments may be nested in another function:

```
var fooBar = fooBar || (function() {
// Unindented comment for folding
   function fooBar() {
      ... do stuff
   };
}());
```

Or in a nested object/array:

```
foo: {
// Another unindented comment for folding
  bar: {
    ... more stuff
  },
// Yet another unindented comment
  baz: [
    ... even more stuff
  ]
}
```

I tried `keep_comment_indentation` to no avail.

Comment: Is this bug an accurate description of what you want? https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/244

Comment: Thanks. I've moved on to a different text editor, though.